# Crystal Reports XI Crosstab summary

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, summary

I have a crosstab report that provides a summarized distinct count of students and a sum of all credits per term. I need a summary that divides the summarized credits by the summarized students. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to solve this with the given information (i.e. not knowing exactly how the data is coming into the report) If the count of students is already passed into the report, this may solve your problem:

1. In your CrossTab Expert, create a new formula @AvgCredits, which is Credits/Students
2. In your CrossTab Expert, place the following fields in the "Summarized Fields" section:

   - Count of Students
   - Sum of Credits
   - Weighted avg of @AvgCredits with StudentsCount  (you may need to add the Formula to the Summarized Fields section first, then click "Change Summary" to change it to a weighted average.)

Comment: Currently i am distinct counting students and summing credits by term. i didn't see weighted avg in the list of choices but it looks like I'm headed the right direction. When I choose weighted avg it asks for what to avg with. I'm guessing that I need this info. Bottom line--sum(credits)/distinctcount(students) by term.